# how to free correctly the pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

This is a function that i've written:

```
uint32_t file_list(char *path, char ***ls){
    DIR *dp;
  //uint32_t i;
  struct stat fileStat;
  struct dirent *ep = NULL;
  uint32_t len, count = 0;
  int file = 0;
  *ls = NULL;
  dp = opendir (path);
  if(dp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "no dir: %s\n", path);
    exit(1);
  }

  ep = readdir(dp);
  while(NULL != ep){
    count++;
    ep = readdir(dp);
  }
  rewinddir(dp);

  *ls = calloc(count, sizeof(char *));
  count = 0;
  ep = readdir(dp);
  while(ep != NULL){
    if((file = open(ep->d_name, O_RDONLY)) < 0){
      perror("apertura file");
      exit(1);
    }
    if(fstat(file, &fileStat) != 0){
      perror("filestat");
      free(*ls);
      close(file);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(file);
    if(S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)){
      len = strlen(ep->d_name);
      (*ls)[count] = malloc(len+5); /* lunghezza stringa + "DIR \n" */
      strcpy((*ls)[count], "DIR "); /* copio DIR */
      strcat((*ls)[count++], ep->d_name); /* concateno la stringa DIR con il nome della dir */
      ep = readdir(dp);
    }
    else{
      (*ls)[count++] = strdup(ep->d_name);
      ep = readdir(dp);
    }
  }
  /*for(i=0; i<count; i++){
    free((*ls)[count]);
  }*/
  (void)closedir(dp);
  return count;
}
```

into the main program i have `char **files` and then the part where i get the count is `count = file_list("./", &files);`
What is my problem?
Everbody know that **the dynamically allocated memory they (the pointers) might refer to**, must be freed but if i free the pointers *(with the for loop)* then into the main program i got an *unexpected behaviour* during the file list *(duplicate file name, no file name, etc)*.
In fact if i don't free the pointers all work perfectly.
So my question is: how to free these pointers?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Ever(y)body know that the pointers must be freed..."_ I seriously hope that there are at least a few programmers out there who know that not pointers, but dynamically allocated memory they _might_ refer to, must be freed. Have you tried to learn the language from a book?

Comment: i know what a pointer is and what it refers to-.-'' you're ao meticulous xD

Comment: Right, you know that. That's why you're here asking what went wrong when you applied this knowledge, huh?

Comment: I've started to learn C 2 months ago. I've understood the 80% of the theory but i have some problems when coding particular things like this. So i have asked this question here. It's simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everbody know that the pointers must be freed but if i free the pointers (with the for loop) then into the main program i got an unexpected behaviour during the file list (duplicate file name, no file name, etc).

Your problem is that you allocate and free in the same function, which render your function basically useless (if I understand correctly anyway). If you free in the same function, after it returns (i.e.: in the "main program"), you end up accessing memory segments that have been released to the operating system, which is undefined behavior.

You'd need two functions, one for the allocation (the one above), and one to free it once you're done, per example:

```
char** files;
uint32_t count = file_list("./", &files);
// do something with files here
file_list_free(&files, count);
```

Keep in mind that your free function will need to know the `count` to prevent a buffer overrun.

There are other problems with your code (e.g.: not checking the return value of `calloc`, etc.), but it would be too long to cover them all here (and don't necessarily relate to your actual question).

Comment: i'm going to fix the calloc retval :) however thanks for your help and thanks also to everybody :D

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your ls parameter is a `char***`, so if that's what you were going for, you need to have an inner loop to free up all of the inner pointers (`**ls`) before freeing up each of the other ones (`*ls`). If you only want double indirection on `ls`, then get rid of one of the *s in your parameter declaration.

(BTW, you needn't use array notation in your loop to free up the pointers (or anywhere else that you access the allocated elements in `ls`). `free(*(ls + count));` is usually the more accepted idiom. Pointer arithmetic works regardless of what the data type is (other than `void`), because the compiler takes that into account.)

Comment: so something like `tmp=count; count=0; for(i=0; i<tmp; i++){free(*(ls+count)); count++;}` will be ok??

Comment: if i have understand i have to write only `free(*(ls+count));` into the function right?

Comment: @polslinux Even better would be: `for (i=0; i<count; i++) { free(*(ls+i)); }` (You're already using i as a loop counter anyway.)

Comment: you're right :) thanks! but i free the pointer into the function then in the main program i got some problems...i need to free them into the main program...how can i do it??

Comment: *"Pointer arithmetic works regardless of what the data type is"*. Just to be clear, arithmetic on `void *` is not allowed according to the standard, although some compilers support it (e.g.: GCC without the `-pedantic` flag). It's not portable, however.

Comment: @netcoder You're right. But then, it won't work for the `*ls[count]` notation, either, because under the hood, whether it's `*ls[count]` or `*(ls+count)`, the compiler generates the same instructions for both. (At least that's what I've been led to believe.)

Comment: I edited the point about pointer arithmetic working regardless of the data type to explicitly exclude `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an extra function, so the caller can free the data when it is done using it:

```
void free_file_list(char ***ls, int count) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        free((*ls)[i]);
    }
    free(*ls);
}
```

Your documentation then must explain that each call to `file_list` must be matched with a call to `free_file_list`.

I would store `count` in a struct like this, though:

```
struct {
    char ***ls;
    int count;
} FILE_LIST;
```

Comment: Just make sure that `count` matches the specification of `file_list`, in that case a `uint32_t`. Using `size_t` would probably be a more appropriate choice here though.

Answer (score 0):

Free the pointers in the main program, after you've finished using them.

You need to free `*ls` as well (again, after you've finished with it).